# Is it possible to create a read-only version of your Facebook news feed?

Tags: facebook

This might sound like a weird question, but I'm wondering how you'd create a version of your own Facebook news feed with the following characteristics:

- All posts are visible, including activity of friends
- The reader isn't allowed to react to, comment on, or share anything, just view
- This tailored news feed can be accessed by inputting login information

I would appreciate any help understanding this.

Comment: There is no allowed way to do this. You can not even get the user’s full newsfeed any more via API.

Comment: [Start here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/user/feed): this is far too broad a question to answer in this form; try out the API there and get back to us if you get stuck. Here's [a very basic example](https://hackernoon.com/graphapi-get-query-fetch-public-facebook-page-feed-3-step-tutorial-example-access-token-auth-post-d7403c717fbf),